# How to import xlsx file with a faster way than Python pandas jupyternotebook

Tags: python, excel, performance, xlsx

I am trying **import multiple xlsx files (with about 1 million rows per file) into python**, to do some **if else, computation, mapping with other files and pivot data** with the dataframe.

The problem here is that there's about 30 files, so that it takes me about **2 hours** to import all files using read_excel. It is really time-consuming because I have to do it on a weekly basis. If anything missing, I have to re-import, and wait next 2 hours to complete the import process. The computer always raise notification about low-memory.

Anyone can help me a **better and faster way** to import those large excel files into dataframe, so that I can handle the tasks after that such as if else, computation, mapping with other files and pivot data.
Thanks so much, I am doing as following

```
os.chdir(r"path")

all = []
columns_to_read = ['OrderID', 'Status', 'Order Amount', 'Total Amount', 'CreateTime', 'PaymentInfo', 'Cash Payable', 'Channel Payable', 'Type', 'Bank', 'Ref_Check', 'OrderSN', 'Transaction ID']  

for f in glob.glob('TVT_info*.xlsx'):
filename = os.path.basename(f)

# Check if 'TVT' is in the filename
if 'TVT' in filename:
    print("reading ", filename)
    
    # Get the sheet names in the Excel file
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(f)
    sheets = [sheet for sheet in xls.sheet_names if 'Data' in sheet]
    
    # Read each sheet with specified columns
    for sheet in sheets:
        df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet, usecols=columns_to_read, dtype= {"Transaction ID":str})
        df['FileName'] = filename
        all.append(df)

# Concatenate all DataFrames
all_df = pd.concat(all)
```

Comment: Perhaps create a pre-processor script that reads one excel file and writes it out to csv in the format you require for your concat'd df. You can then run multiple of them in parallel to generate a folder full of csv files. Finally once all the files have been processed run your main script that just loads them all.